# master slave and changing IP addresses

Tags: ros, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm on the university network and they can't offer static ip addresses. the main problem is when driving the robot through different wifi networks and getting a new IP.

i have the robot set up as the master (or i could make it slave if i have to) and i came up with a work around sort of like DynDNS, where once i get a new ip i send it to my google drive and can access it.

problem is dynamically changing the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP variables. I'm pretty sure as soon as u start a node they're locked to that node. is there no way to change it while the node is running?

otherwise it's essentially required that the computers running ROS and communicating together have static IPs.

if i can't dynamically change the IP addresses of running nodes i guess the best solution then, for a mobile computer running nodes is to have an 4G/LTE modem attached to it? am i right in assuming that this should provide me with the same IP address throughout its lifetime?

or maybe i'll have to make some "communication" nodes on both the robot and the controller.

thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132931/master-slave-and-changing-ip-addresses/) by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-25**:
I am not a network expert at all, but if you disconnect and reconnect to another network won't all connections be broken and would need to be reestablished anyways?

**Comment by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on 2014-02-25**:
i sort of tested this today. i had the master running on the robot computer (the one i expect to move through the wifi networks) and hit the wifi on/off button to shut down the wifi. the uni network is a bit weird because it gave me the same ip address. but anyways. once i reconnected the internet..

**Comment by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on 2014-02-25**:
.. (sorry, not internet, network) the control pc (which was running a joy node) was still able to communicate with the master/robot and drive it round. also when the master was dced i couldn't view any topics on the control, but when it was connected again i could see all the topics that were...

**Comment by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on 2014-02-25**:
running. and this is all without restarting any nodes...

did the same with the control pc (disconnecting). once it reconnected was still able to drive the robot around. but like said. i'm scared the ip will be locked when nodes are created. one thing that might fix this is hosts and a DNS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

does anyone think that by using hostnames and setting that up. then changing the table where IPs are mapped to hostnames when the IP changes this will solve it? or will it only resolve the hostname once when nodes are created?

thanks for all help and comments

---

Originally posted by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) with karma: 96 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-25**:
Try setting up network such that the machines are reachable via hostnames, i.e. do not use ROS_IP (see http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup). Now what happens when the IP address changes I am not sure. Don't know how robust the ROS transport. New connections and requests should be ok,

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-25**:
but not sure what happens to established connections between nodes (i.e. subscribed topics).

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-25**:
I'm not sure what you mean by "table where IPs are mapped to hostnames".

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-25**:
And lastly, try to edit your question rather than posting follow-ups are answers ;)

**Comment by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on 2014-02-25**:
thanks for the reply. will try mucking around with hostname. with the "table" thing, i was thinking that that's how hostnames work. like there is some server that stores (hostname, ip address) pairs and if a hosts ip address changes it updates the pair. and other computers look up this "table"...

**Comment by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on 2014-02-25**:
to get names. ROS could be smart about this and i guess check the server for changes in IP addresses. and change them accordingly. but i don't know. i'll try it out today.

sorry about posting in the wrong places. thanks

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-25**:
Yes, this table is called DNS and proper setup of networking should include some form of DNS serivce, possibly locally.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-25**:
P.S.: Not sure if you can use some form of VPN tunnel between the machines that is robust to network changes such that from the ros perspective IPs don't change.

**Comment by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on 2014-02-25**:
that's a good idea. if the DNS doesn't pull through i'll give it a try. also got a 3g modem now and possibly 4g in the future so might not need to bother =). thanks